# @media and "the best way" to create "responsive" websites

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am looking into `@media` and was wondering what would be the most effective way of creating a site that changes depending on the width of the webpage.

Here's what I am using at the moment *(background color change is to show the changes)*:

```
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
    body {
        background:#000;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px) {
    body {
        background:#555;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
    body {
        background:#AAA;
    }
}
```

Would writing out a `@media` query each time be the most *effective/"best"* way to do this?

Comment: The technical term for what you want to achieve is "responsive" (web site). Just to make your googling easier :)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to go 'mobile first', which means to develop for mobile screens and then edit you styles in media queries depending on what needs changing for different screen sizes.

'`min-width`' means it will effect styles for screen sizes that have a minimum width of the value you set, so there's no need for `max-width`.

```
 @media screen and (min-width: <Enter width in px>) { }

 @media screen and (min-width: <Enter width in px>) { }

 @media screen and (min-width: <Enter width in px>) { }
```

Comment: If you found this answer to be correct you should up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best way because the best way is to define your media queries as needed.  Device sizes are constantly changing and if you build your site based on someone else's recommended sizes, those sizes could very well be obsolete in less than a year..

[Microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com) is actually one of my favorite examples.  If you take a look at their site and expand it as far as your screen allows you'll notice that the page is designed to look good at every pixel size, not just at preset points.

> Start with the small screen (that you want to support) first, then expand until it looks like shit. Time for a breakpoint! -[Stephen Hay](https://twitter.com/stephenhay)

### Further

- [7 Habits of Highly Effective Media Queries](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/)